# Group results by field but show all and display in custom order

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm currently using the following to show a list of players

```
    $sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT pla.*, tea.*
    FROM Players pla
    INNER JOIN Teams tea USING (TeamID)
    WHERE TeamID = '$TeamID'
SQL;
```

I'd like to now arrange these results by sorting grouping them in to positions. So for example all of the goalkeepers shown together in alphabetical order, then all of the defenders.

I know that I can

```
ORDER BY Position
```

However that will throw "attackers" first and I'd like the positions to display as Goalkeepers, Defenders, Midfielders, Attackers. Would I need to do 4 separate queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do a conditional order by that will do what you want

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN position = "Goalkeepers" THEN 1
        WHEN position = "Defenders" THEN 2
        WHEN position = "Midfielders" THEN 3
        WHEN position = "Attackers" THEN 4
        ELSE 5
    END,
    name
```

I added position at the end to order the results in ascending order after grouping them by their position

Comment: That's working perfectly apart from the names aren't alphabetical. Is it possible to add a sub order?

Comment: @BN83 I added position at the end to make them alphabetical so that should do it

Comment: ignore that, I changed Position to Name and their name's order correctly now. Cheers